# Make sure methods run ones at the time

Tags: java, multithreading

I made a java program with threads and sometimes the threads use a static method the problem is that the method may only run once at the time. So if the method is already running it shouldn't start another time but wait and then start again.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply mark that static method as `synchronized` and it will ensure mutual exclusion: 2 threads won't be able to run it concurrently, one of them will have to wait until the other completes the execution of the method:

```
public static synchronized void method() {
    //this part can only be executed by one thread at a time
}
```

this notation is equivalent to using your class's monitor as a lock for the operation, i.e.:

```
class YourClass {
    public static void method() {
        synchronized(YourClass.class) {
            //this part can only be executed by one thread at a time
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gray I have clarified it, without going into class loader consideration as this could become confusing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"word" `synchronized`  will help you

```
public static synchronized void method() {
....code here 
notify();}
```